# windows 7 stucks on hibernate resume

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I recently changed my motherboard to MSI G41TM-P33. Reinstalled win7 Home Premium x64 with all updates and everything is fine except hibernate mode.

Systems goes into hibernate without any problems, but resume process stuck after completing win7 logo (with some lags). Hard drive is silent, system is not hanged, just nothing happens. I can restart by ctrl+alt+del and after that system asks me to try again or to leave my session and start from scratch.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my previous MSI motherboard. It started after updating network drivers from windows autoupdate. I was able to fix it by updating my BIOS. Some people said that they were able to fix it by installing new network drivers from MSI (this did not help for me).

Comment: installed MSI live utility for drivers and BIOS update but their server is unavailable ( Hoping this is just weekend troubles

Comment: updated BIOS solved the problem )